# Creating a spring bean with Configuration annotation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

guys, I want to register and inject a spring bean with the Configuration annotation but without success. Here is the bean I want to create on a abstract level:

```
public class MyBean{

    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    private String someString;

    public MyBean(AnotherBean anotherBean, String someString) {
        this.anotherBean= anotherBean;
        this.someString= someString;
    }

    public MyBean(){}

    public MyPojo someMethod(MyPojo oject, final String anyString) {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

Here is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    private static final String SOME_STRING = "someString";

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("anotherBean")
    private AnotherBean otherBean;


    @Bean(name = "myBean")
    public MyBean getMyBean(){
        MyBean myBean= new MyBean(otherBean, SOME_STRING );
        return myBean;
    }
}
```

And I declare in the application context the configuration bean:

```
<bean class="configuration.package.BeanConfiguration"/>
```

So the the problem is that the spring container creates an BeanConfiguration object but the getMyBean() method is never hit, so my bean is never registered and when I try to inject it an exception telling me that the bean can not be autowired, so it is not injected(and that is normal, because the bean is not registered). Here is the stack trace

```
10:33:03.322 [http-apr-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   'bet': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private   my.bean.package.MyBean   
my.bean.package.MyBean; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type   [my.bean.package.MyBean] found for   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[AbstractBeanFactory$1.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[AbstractBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[AbstractApplicationContext.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459) ~[FrameworkServlet.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [HttpServletBean.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.1.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526) [catalina.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.9]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.9]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60-ea]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private my.bean.package.MyBean my.bean.package.myBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [my.bean.package.MyBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[InjectionMetadata.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [my.bean.package.MyBean] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) ~[DefaultListableBeanFactory.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486) ~[AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.class:3.2.2.RELEASE]
... 39 common frames omitted
```

So I can't see why my bean is not registered, so if anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: Add `<context:component-scan />` to your xml file and remove  `BeanConfiguration` from xml. And where do you create `AnotherBean`?

Comment: Actually the <context:component-scan /> works, but to be more precise the thing I was missing was the <context:annotation-config/>... And the answer for the AnotherBean creation is- in the application-context.

Comment: No, `component-scan` enables the functionality of `annotation-config`, as well. So, theoretically, you shouldn't need `annotation-config`.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because you use private with inject and you dont have the set function, and the other problem is because you dont have the  `<bean class="....MyBean"/>` in your xml configuration

Comment: But as you can see I am creating the object with Configuration- so I am creating the object with its constructor and why do I need the setters? Also you can see I am declaring the bean with the annotation Bean and I don't need to declare it in the application-context. Correct me if I am wrong.